# How to assign value of key to a list in python?

Tags: python, list

For example, I have the following:

```
newdict = {0: [5], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2]}

initiallist = [5,2,2,1]
```

I would like to get the output: `[0,1,2,1]`.

I tried different methods, but it did not work? Any suggestions? I need help with this.

Comment: How do the two inputs map to the output?

Comment: It is not clear what operation(s) you want to perform on `newdict` and `initiallist` to get the desired output.  Perhaps you could describe what you want to happen, or give some more examples?

Comment: how do you know if the output is `[0,1,2,1]` or `[0,1,1,1]` or `[0,2,2,1]`

Comment: it depends on what is the value of the key

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to go on a bit of a limb here.  This gives something close to your desired result:

```py
def get_counts_for_keys(dictionary, keys_to_check):
    return [len(dictionary.get(x, [])) for x in keys_to_check]

newdict = {0: [5], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2]}
initiallist = [5,2,2,1]

result = get_counts_for_keys(newdict, initiallist)
print(result)  # Prints [0, 1, 1, 2], not [0, 1, 2, 1] as desired.
```

Is this anything like what you are after, or completely off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

Answering title's question, you can list dict's items, just as these:

```
newdict = {0: [5], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2]}
a_list = list(newdict.items())
a_list
```

> [(0, [5]), (1, [2, 1]), (2, [2])]

Then you can get key by their list position, such as:

```
a_list[0][0], a_list[0][1], a_list[1][0],a_list[1][1],a_list[2][0],a_list[2][1]
```

> (0, [5], 1, [2, 1], 2, [2])